# Maximum webpart property size in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

What is the maximum property size (how many bytes can I store in a string property for example) in a webpart in Sharepoint 2010?

In [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585794%28v=office.11%29.aspx) it is set in the Web.config to 1048576.

```
<SharePoint>
    <WebPartLimits PropertySize="1048576"/>
```

In my Sharepoint 2010 installation I have a similar entry in the Web.config:

```
<SharePoint>
    <WebPartLimits MaxZoneParts="50" PropertySize="1048576" />
```

That means I can store a maximum of 1 MB in a property.

But I ran a test and was able to store 16300000 chars (about 16 MB in UTF8) in a string property and I stopped adding more just because that is more than enough for me.

But I wonder why this is possible as the Web.config says it is max. 1 MB?